# After updating my bios kali linux not anymore showing up

Tags: grub, upgrade, bios

After trying some troubleshooting and most common fixes like

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036980/grub-does-not-load-after-bios-update

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?35205-GRUB-loader-not-shown-Dual-boot-Windows-10-and-Kali-linux-2016-2

I had no luck resolving this issue. Under is paste bin output from boot repair disk which gave me also no success. Linux is instatalled on sdc and I am at the moment really stuck with this. **I'm trying avoid reinstalling kali because I don`t want to lose current progress.**

```
boot-repair-4ppa171                                              [20220202_1003]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sde.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/kali/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 has 
                       3519033343 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 7814000639 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

sdc3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdd2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sde1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 16408 of /dev/sde1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 7 on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: NVIDIA Corporation from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0007,0006,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,bdbc0ab2-f7fc-45b8-b943-7f6813dc7f44,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...d................
Boot0001  CT480BX500SSD1    BBS(HD,,0x0)..BO
Boot0002  TOSHIBA MD04ACA400    BBS(HD,,0x0)..BO
Boot0003  WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0  BBS(HD,,0x0)..BO
Boot0004  SanDisk SSD PLUS 1000GB   BBS(HD,,0x0)..BO
Boot0005  Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,bdbc0ab2-f7fc-45b8-b943-7f6813dc7f44,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
Boot0006* UEFI: Intenso Rainbow Line 8.07, Partition 1  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x53dcc,0x800,0x752800)..BO
Boot0007* Intenso Rainbow Line 8.07 BBS(HD,,0x0)..BO

7e09c5e1912455db662fa8254318faa2   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi
43388be20e42992dda6fc55874f4ec3a   sda1/kali/grubx64.efi
7e09c5e1912455db662fa8254318faa2   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
46be41b32d03ed3521b602d790327d85   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdd : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda4    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdc1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdc2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdd2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdd2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda4    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdc1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdc
sdc2    : is-sepboot,   no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdc
sdd2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdd

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk identifier: D1362C48-8F4C-4EB6-8652-4BA57FE0AF47
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3     239616 936349044 936109429 446.4G Microsoft basic data
sda4  936349696 937697279   1347584   658M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk identifier: 57F6C561-CCF3-2244-ADDA-573BD7C017C1
      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048      34815      32768   16M Microsoft reserved
sdb2  34816 7814035455 7814000640  3.7T Microsoft basic data
Disk sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 90F157A3-9139-47C0-9657-1041D1E8ED1B
        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sdc1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
sdc2  1050624    2050047     999424   488M Linux filesystem
sdc3  2050048 1953523711 1951473664 930.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000207286272 bytes, 1953529856 sectors
Disk identifier: 89688769-B6BA-48A9-8801-5BA5A59E8382
      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sdd1   2048      34815      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sdd2  34816 1953527807 1953492992 931.5G Microsoft basic data
Disk sde: 3.7 GiB, 3932160000 bytes, 7680000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00053dcc
      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sde1  *     2048 7679999 7677952  3.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk zram0: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram1: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram2: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram3: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram4: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram5: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram6: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram7: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram8: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram9: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram10: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram11: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram12: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram13: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram14: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors
Disk zram15: 498.2 MiB, 522391552 bytes, 127537 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:480GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA CT480BX500SSD1:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:479GB:479GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:479GB:480GB:690MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
sdb:4001GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA MD04ACA4:;
1:1049kB:17.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:17.8MB:4001GB:4001GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdc:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD10JPVX-22J:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:538MB:1050MB:512MB:ext2::;
3:1050MB:1000GB:999GB:::;
sdd:1000GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA SanDisk SSD PLUS:;
1:1049kB:17.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:17.8MB:1000GB:1000GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sde:3932MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Intenso Rainbow Line:;
1:1049kB:3932MB:3931MB:fat32::boot, lba;

Free space (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:457863MiB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA CT480BX500SSD1:;
1:0.02MiB:1.00MiB:0.98MiB:free;
1:457202MiB:457202MiB:0.32MiB:free;
1:457860MiB:457863MiB:2.82MiB:free;
sdb:3815448MiB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA MD04ACA4:;
1:0.02MiB:1.00MiB:0.98MiB:free;
1:3815447MiB:3815448MiB:0.82MiB:free;
sdc:953870MiB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD10JPVX-22J:;
1:0.02MiB:1.00MiB:0.98MiB:free;
1:953869MiB:953870MiB:0.69MiB:free;
sdd:953872MiB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA SanDisk SSD PLUS:;
1:0.02MiB:1.00MiB:0.98MiB:free;
1:953871MiB:953872MiB:0.98MiB:free;
sde:3750MiB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Intenso Rainbow Line:;
1:0.03MiB:1.00MiB:0.97MiB:free;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE      UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                      
├─sda1 vfat        5066-646A                            bdbc0ab2-f7fc-45b8-b943-7f6813dc7f44             EFI system partition
├─sda2                                                  0f1430a4-23ef-4a83-a3b4-b67931b72b2a             Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs        F292B2D492B29D13                     c6c8eff3-d783-48c1-833d-98857411b006             Basic data partition
└─sda4 ntfs        483A8C8C3A8C7928                     263a732d-3e4d-4544-9764-7392764ee90a             
sdb                                                                                                      
├─sdb1                                                  b8ea5ef4-c585-44db-98e6-c7267dd40fa6             Microsoft reserved partition
└─sdb2 ntfs        3458A35A58A31A1E                     c014db28-6b71-4500-b2e7-7db5c0235944             Basic data partition
sdc                                                                                                      
├─sdc1 vfat        CD49-A7E0                            57f960b6-1433-402b-85e8-e0991a54fa77             
├─sdc2 ext2        e11cf054-ff95-43d4-939d-f22f3c16d2ca 37890f0f-0f9e-4bb2-a850-b8b5d4fc5f03             
└─sdc3 crypto_LUKS d5a6aafa-aa59-400f-a7bd-4c88b24ce5cf e4e6ee75-674b-43cd-98ef-166c677ad0a2             
sdd                                                                                                      
├─sdd1                                                  a432912d-96f8-430f-a928-83470bad87c3             Microsoft reserved partition
└─sdd2 ntfs        6C3AE85E3AE82734                     0a38daf8-f8dc-4bee-b9c6-79dc40b8c32f             Basic data partition
sde                                                                                                      
└─sde1 vfat        70E9-6D80                            00053dcc-01                          BOOT-REPAIR 

Mount points (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

            Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1    66.9M  30% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda3   310.8G  30% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4      89M  86% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sdb2     3.2T  12% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
/dev/sdc1     511M   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc1
/dev/sdc2   241.3M  42% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc2
/dev/sdd2   882.2G   5% /mnt/boot-sav/sdd2
/dev/sde1     2.8G  24% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ________________________________________________________________

/dev/sda1   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda3   ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda4   ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb2   ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdc1   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdc2   rw,relatime,stripe=4
/dev/sdd2   ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sde1   ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

======================== sdc2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Kali GNU/Linux   bc4e6a13-870f-4b7f-a9d8-b488249df7ed
Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.15.0-kali3-amd64   bc4e6a13-870f-4b7f-a9d8-b488249df7ed
Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.15.0-kali2-amd64   bc4e6a13-870f-4b7f-a9d8-b488249df7ed
Windows Boot Manager (on sda1)   osprober-efi-5066-646A
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
System setup   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sdc2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.537110329 = 0.576717824    grub/grub.cfg                                  9
   0.688476562 = 0.739246080    vmlinuz-5.15.0-kali2-amd64                    13
   0.570297241 = 0.612352000    vmlinuz-5.15.0-kali3-amd64                    13
   0.953986168 = 1.024334848    initrd.img-5.15.0-kali2-amd64                 24
   0.957031250 = 1.027604480    initrd.img-5.15.0-kali3-amd64                 31

====================== sde1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)

========================= sde1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sde1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sde1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================


/dev/sda1: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sda2: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sda4: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000001

/dev/sdb1: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sdd1: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000
Unknown BootLoader on sdc3

00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  62 20 82 5b 70 53 20 3a  |........b .[pS :|
00000070  12 83 15 4d f5 70 41 89  5b 18 2b a1 9e d1 61 1e  |...M.pA.[.+...a.|
00000080  c2 42 94 dc e1 96 81 1e  fc a9 b8 d4 62 48 45 2a  |.B..........bHE*|
00000090  70 0a 33 61 66 76 e8 53  3b 51 f4 c3 c7 e4 b0 3f  |p.3afv.S;Q.....?|
000000a0  a6 c9 c0 37 f4 10 99 97  64 35 61 36 61 61 66 61  |...7....d5a6aafa|
000000b0  2d 61 61 35 39 2d 34 30  30 66 2d 61 37 62 64 2d  |-aa59-400f-a7bd-|
000000c0  34 63 38 38 62 32 34 63  65 35 63 66 00 00 00 00  |4c88b24ce5cf....|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001c0  63 09 25 91 9f 09 3c 4c  08 70 cf 39 2f e4 c1 d0  |c.%...<L.p.9/...|
000001d0  06 46 92 fe 3d f1 8d 8e  17 b9 93 61 48 66 a5 05  |.F..=......aHf..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200




Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix
```

---

First of all thank you for you answer.
I tried above solution but with second command I got output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /create /d "GRUB for Kali Linux" {fwbootmgr}
```

> A description for the new entry must be specified. Run "bcdedit /?"
> for command line assistance. The parameter is incorrect

After that I took look at manual for bcdedit and tried:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /create {fwbootmgr} /d "GRUB for Kali"
```

Which gave me output like this:

> An error occurred while attempting the specified create operation.
> The specified entry already exists.
> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

I got like you can see no output for `<GUID>` after looking for commands I found cmd for getting wanted `<GUID>`

```
bcdedit /enum firmware
```

From there I found out which one I need and just copied other two commands

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /set {99c2f727-837f-11ec-87d3-806e6f6e6963} device partition=X:
```

> The operation completed successfully.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /set {99c2f727-837f-11ec-87d3-806e6f6e6963} path \efi\kali\grubx64.efi
```

> The operation completed successfully.

After that I just restarted PC with thought that´s it, but problem still persist.

Comment: Here is original pastbin file from boot repair disk https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/fpnzGtrtsr/

Comment: I just updated link try now and tell me if it is problem still there. (https://pastebin.com/gQudmXFA)

Comment: I've added the pastebin for you. It really is much easier for people to try and answer a question when all the information is in the same place

Comment: Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a UEFI system. The `No boot loader is installed in the MBR of ...` means "No **legacy BIOS boot loader** is installed in the MBR of ...", which you can completely ignore, as legacy BIOS boot loaders are completely irrelevant to you.

The Boot-Repair results indicate that Kali's bootloader is actually still there at `/efi/kali/grubx64.efi` of your `sda1`.

What you have lost are the UEFI NVRAM boot variables, causing the UEFI boot settings (those you can view with `sudo efibootmgr -v` in Linux) to vanish. Windows still boots because it installs a second copy of its initial UEFI boot file (`/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi` on your `sda1`) to the EFI System Partition (ESP for short) by default. This is called the UEFI fallback/removable-media boot file, and only one OS per ESP can have one.

(Only one ESP per disk is recommended; multiple ESPs on a single disks should work, but is probably much less well tested by the firmware developers.)

When you boot Windows (at least Windows 10 or newer) on a UEFI system, it will check its own UEFI NVRAM settings, and if it finds Windows has been started using the fallback and the actual NVRAM settings are missing, it will automatically rebuild its own UEFI NVRAM boot settings (most likely overwriting whatever was in the `Boot0000` variable before).

If you have a live Linux boot media you can use to boot the system in UEFI mode, you can use the `efibootmgr` command as root like this:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \\efi\\kali\\grubx64.efi -L "GRUB for Kali Linux"
```

This will re-create the bootloader entry and automatically add it to the boot order at the same time.

---

You should remember these instructions, as the same is likely to happen again with every BIOS update on this particular hardware. (Some UEFI implementations will preserve the boot variables over firmware updates; yours apparently doesn't, unless things improve with future updates.)

Comment: Booting in Linux live boot and entering command from above solve the issue. I only have to little bit make order for booting option but that I can manage. Thank you one more time for your arrangement :D